# Make only certain sections of UITableView editable

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, nsindexpath

I have a UITableView with multiple sections, and I want to make only one section editable (swipe to delete).

I have a feeling I have to do something in the `willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath`delegate method, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

return YES for allowing editable, otherwise NO.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below function for what you look for:

```
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Return YES to whichever row you want to edit.